# Collection of the same entity within an entity

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, join, orm

I'm trying to create an entity that has the same entity type as a collection.
I have a "view" of this entity in the database, and it has the org_id and the root_id. The org_id in the entity is mapped with the @Id column.

In the "view" of the sql, I don't have a foreign key mapped. Is it possible to map this foreign key in hibernate / JPA somehow, or specify a query to do so? I'm using spring data, so JPQL would work.

The code looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class SupplierData {

@Id
@Column(name = "org_uuid")
private String orgUUID;
@Column(name = "root_uuid")
private String rootUUID;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="root_uuid", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private SupplierData rootSupplierData;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="rootSupplierData", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, 
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<SupplierData> supplierDatas=new HashSet<>();
    // ......
```

But a findall query doesn't show any results. If I remove the ManyToOne and OneToMany, all of my data is shown.

I think I'm missing a foreign key relation in the database, but I can't add that myself. Is there a way to map that myself in the jpa annotations?

Comment: A missing FK constraint shouldn't matter. Please post the query you're trying to use

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. I had to remove one of the rootUUID references. I had both the string and the object. I can use one or the other.

For example I remove 
    @Column(name = "root_uuid")
.   private String rootUUID;

And it works. That's because  @JoinColumn(name="root_uuid"... Already references the column.